# Create Directive that Inserts HTML Outside of Where it's Used

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created an AngularJS directive. This directive needs to insert an HTML element as a child of the `body` element. This element will need to contain another custom component, defined as a directive.

I've tried `transclude`ing the directive, that's not allowing me to achieve the desired result; placing the element as a direct child of `body`. An approach I was thinking of was to, in some manner, grab the markup from the `templateUrl` and inject that *"angularly"* into the DOM just before the closing `body` tag.

*I'm really trying to stay open-minded with the concept of using AngularJS daily, these "things" are making that difficult.*

Comment: It feels like your code architecture become a mess, if you need tasks like that.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: it's a normal directive, nothing to show. the concept and goal is explained well enough. the directive functions as written. just need to access the html template and insert it at a specific location in the `HTML`.

Comment: Can you just use the `link` function in the directive to create some new element and append it to the DOM? Assuming you need things from $scope, you could use the $compile provider to compile the element against $scope before you append it to the body.

Comment: [angular-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) has directives that attach to the body. You should check out their code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @MatthewGreen reviewing that now ...

Comment: @Hacknightly so, `compile`ing the element with the `scope` ***before*** appending it the raw JS way is a "sanctioned" approach?

Comment: @culturalanomoly sorry for the late reply but I would say yes. The team I work on uses an approach like this and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive's `link` function, try the following:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // The template of the widget to be added elsewhere.
    // This is different than your directive's own template.
    var tpl = '<div>some body widget</div>';

    // Compile your template, defining a custom cloneAttachFn
    // to attach the element where you want in the DOM.
    var appended = $compile(tpl)(scope, function(clonedElement) {
       $('body').append(clonedElement);
    });
}
```

The benefit of doing this is that your appended template is compiled with the same scope as its "sibling" directive. You can set properties on `$scope` that trigger digest cycles; access scope methods defined in the controller from the appended template; and all other normal directive things you would expect to be able to do.

This still feels like the Angular way in spite of the stretching. Perhaps I've missed something, but this approach seems to work for me.

Also – be sure to inject `$compile` into your directive, and be sure to do cleanup on scope destroy:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    appended.remove();
});
```

Docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile